# Easiest plot result of numpy.polyfit?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy.polyfit to fit a polynomial to my dataset.

```
x = vline[vline.columns[0]]
y = vline[vline.columns[1]]
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
z = array([ 7.48695862e-08, -6.73333047e-05,  2.69276073e-02,  2.90345187e+00])
```

What's the easiest way to plot this polynomial?

Right now, I am manually creating an equation like

7.48695862\cdot10^{-8}x^{3}+-6.73333047\cdot10^{-5}x^{2}+2.69276073\cdot10^{-2}x+2.90345187

And then plotting the graph using mathplotlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html#numpy.polyval):

```
z = array([ 7.48695862e-08, -6.73333047e-05,  2.69276073e-02,  2.90345187e+00])
x2 = np.arange(-100, 100, .1) # Something relevant for you
plt.plot(x2, np.polyval(z, x2))
```

You can probably replace `np.arange(-100, 100, .1)` by something more generic based on your data.